# Complex asserts on collections

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertj

I have an actual list of strings generated in my integration test and an expected list of substrings. It is trivial to assert that the collections are equal, e.g.:

```
assertThat(actual).containsExactly(expected);
```

In my case it is a bit more difficult though, because I would effectively like to have a `containsExactlySubstring()` function -- that is I would like to assert that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the actual strings and expected substrings. Is there a neat (descriptive) way to implement it out of the box?

EXAMPLES:

```
expected = {"abc", "def", "ghi"}
actualPass = {"#abc", "#ghi", "#def"}
actualFail1 = {"abc", "def"}
actualFail2 = {"#abc", "#ghi", "#abc"}
actualFail3 = {"#abc", "#ghi", "#xyz"}
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what is expected, what you mean by "substring" is unclear

Comment: @RC. thanks for the comment, added a few examples

Comment: It's unlikely there would be an off-the-shelf comparator for such a contrived case, but it should be fairly easy to write a custom assertion, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a [condition](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html) that would be verified on all elements using `are(condition) / have(condition)` or as [kryger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240557/kryger) suggested use an [element comparator](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#custom-comparison-strategy).

Hope it helps.